# Поиск двух минимальных цифр в составе числа

Tags: pascal

Не могу найти ошибку. Одна из минимальных цифр находится, а вторая нет.

```
Writeln ('a=');

Readln (a);

min1:=a mod 10;

While a<>0 do begin

a:=a div 10; n:=a mod 10;

if n<min1 then

begin

min2:=min1;

min:=n;

end else

if n<min2 then min2:=n; end;

Writeln ('min1=',min1,' min2=',min2);
```

Comment: Используйте форматирование кода  а то так код читать ну очень неудобно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не инициализируете `min2`. В этом проблема: меньше 0 чисел нет.
По крайней мере в нашей системе счисления.

Еще комментарии по коду:

1. Инициализируйте `min1 = 9` и `min2 = 9`. Разберитесь, почему это правильно.
2. Поменяйте местами `a:=a div 10;` и `n:=a mod 10;`.
3. Никогда не пишите несколько команд в одну строчку. Это затрудняет чтение и отладку.
4. Поставьте проверку на `a = 0` и `a < 10`. Разберитесь с отрицательными числами.
5. Используйте отступы.